# Sockets with Python: Listen to Commands to start or stop a loop

Tags: python, sockets, while-loop

I have an alarm that I want to run in a loop. I want to be able to start and stop this loop remotely using sockets. I'm having issues to continuously listen for commands and to start and stop this alarm loop.

There are some similar posts that don't have answers:

[How to do a continuous "while loop" in Python with socket listening and waiting every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194185/how-to-do-a-continuous-while-loop-in-python-with-socket-listening-and-waiting)

[Python socket: trying to receive a new TCP message within a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60368268/python-socket-trying-to-receive-a-new-tcp-message-within-a-while-loop)

The problem is that the socket is in a while loop and allows for the alarm loop to start, but now I can't receive the message to stop. How do I continue to listen to start or stop the alarm loop? Below is my attempt to see if there are new data (STOP), but it then stops the alarm loop to listen for incoming messages.

```
import time
import socket
import sys




mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    mysock.bind(("", 1234))
except:
    print("Failed to bind")
    sys.exit()

mysock.listen(5)
while True:
    conn,addr = mysock.accept()
    data = conn.recv(1000)
    state = b"ALARM OFF"
    print(data)
    if not data:
        break
    if data == b'ALARM ON':
        state = b"ALARM ON"
        print(state)
    if data == b'SILENT':
        state = b"ALARM OFF"
        print(state)
    while state == b"ALARM ON":
        print("BEEP BEEP BEEP")
        conn,addr = mysock.accept()
        new_data = conn.recv(1000)
        print(new_data)
        if new_data:
            state == new_data
    print(state)
    conn.sendall(state)
conn.close()
mysock.close()
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [multithreading](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+multithreading)?

Comment: Not really. All of the simple examples I've seen on threading have to do with mutually exclusive functions. These two loops are dependent on each other. Looking at the simple examples, I don't know how to implement it with my application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use a thread to print the message over and over again:

```
import threading
import time
import socket
import sys

alarm_on = False   # Flag to stop the thread

# The thread function
def thread_function():
    while alarm_on:
        print("BEEP BEEP BEEP")
        time.sleep(1)


mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    mysock.bind(("", 1234))
except:
    print("Failed to bind")
    sys.exit()

thrd = None
mysock.listen(5)
while True:
    conn,addr = mysock.accept()
    while True:
        conn,addr = mysock.accept()
        data = conn.recv(1000)
        state = b"ALARM OFF"
        print(data)
        if not data:
            break
        if data == b'ALARM ON':
            state = b"ALARM ON"
            print(state)
            alarm_on = True
            # Start the thread
            thrd = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)
            thrd.start()
        if data == b'SILENT':
            state = b'ALARM OFF'
            print(state)
            # Set the flag to stop the thread
            alarm_on = False            
        conn.sendall(state)
    conn.close()
mysock.close()
```

Comment: The thread should start after the `accept()` and do all the reading and sending, not just start after the first read. Otherwise an unresponsive client can still hang up the server.

Comment: @user207421 Sure, the server should be threaded as well, but the goal of the answer is not to rewrite OP's entire program but to demonstrate adding a simple thread to print the alarm message. Hopefully this will motivate OP to study up on writing multithreaded programs in all its complexity - which is beyond the scope of a simple SO post.